# How to copy 1st column elements to 2nd column of an matrix in c program

Tags: c, arrays

How to copy 1st column elements to 2nd column of an matrix in c program

Input

```
2 3 4
5 6 7
7 8 9
```

Output

```
2 2 3 3 4 4
5 5 6 6 7 7
7 7 8 8 9 9
```

Comment: Please try solving this independently before posting a question, or click [edit] and post your best attempt.

Comment: @user1340391 The example is not clear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @user1340391  And how the matrices are defined?

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays are predefined then the code can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M   3
#define N   3

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[M][N] =
    {
        { 2, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6, 7 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    int b[M][2*N];

    for ( size_t m = 0; m < M; m++ )
    {
        for ( size_t n = 0; n < N; n++ ) printf( "%d ", a[m][n] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    for ( size_t n = 0, i = 0; n < N; n++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++, i++ )
        {
            for ( size_t m = 0; m < M; m++ ) b[m][i] = a[m][n]; 
        }

    }

    for ( size_t m = 0; m < M; m++ )
    {
        for ( size_t n = 0; n < 2 * N; n++ ) printf( "%d ", b[m][n] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 3 4 
5 6 7 
7 8 9 

2 2 3 3 4 4 
5 5 6 6 7 7 
7 7 8 8 9 9
```

That is you have to copy columns "manually" using loops.

Otherwise you need to allocate the second array dynamically or to use a variable length array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, this is you may try:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3

int main(){
    int inMat[SIZE][SIZE];
    int outMat[SIZE][SIZE*2];

    int i, j, k;

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &inMat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        for(j=0, k =0; j<SIZE*2; k++, j++){
            outMat[i][j] = inMat[i][k];
            outMat[i][++j] = inMat[i][k];
        }
    }

    printf("Input Matrix:\n");
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%d ", inMat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Output Matrix:\n");
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        for(j=0; j<SIZE*2; j++) {
            printf("%d ", outMat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
2 3 4
5 6 7
7 8 9
Input Matrix:
2 3 4 
5 6 7 
7 8 9 
Output Matrix:
2 2 3 3 4 4 
5 5 6 6 7 7 
7 7 8 8 9 9
```